# Matching list of values on multiple columns in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

Given a table with a composite primary key, say `a` and `b`. If I have a list of pairs that I would like to query for, say,

```
pairs = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1]]
```

How can I filter using these in a dataset?

The result in SQL would look like

```
WHERE (a, b) IN ((1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1))
```

There's `DB.values()` that can be used to express the right side, but I'm not sure how to get the actual filtering into a dataset.

Comment: I don't think you can `WHERE IN` on pairs. You could make a temporary table and try and `JOIN` to it.

Comment: @tadman see Jeremy's answer below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DB[:table].where([:a, :b]=>[[1,1], [2,2], [2,1]])
# SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((a, b) IN ((1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1)))
```

Comment: Well that was surprisingly easy.